# Is it okay saying "What the deal with him is that ...."

Tags: word-usage

I am non-native english speaker, and I just realized that I use expression like this a lot 
"what the deal with is that he is too laid-back and  reckless". I just checked on the internet and I did not find any links corresponding to this particular expression. So I am wondering whether it is a even a valid expression?

I guess it is same as "what I want to do" or "what I have in my mind"

Comment: If you want to use this expression, your syntax is off.  Try "The deal with him is that he is too..." or "His deal is that he is too...".  Someone's *deal* is their problem or troublesome aspect.

Comment: Just like you'd say "His problem *is* that he is too ...", you'd have to say "What the deal with him is *is* that he is too ...", and that would be extremely confusing (two identical words in a row). So say "His deal is ..."

Comment: (No, what your sposta say is "What the deal with him is, is that ...":-)

Comment: @JohnLawler  That's very formal. Colloquial would be “‘adeal withis bozo zeezdoo ...” Stronger expressions may be substituted for *bozo*. :-)

Comment: I don't really see that even a grammatically valid version of *"what the deal with is that"* is even worth saying at all. It doesn't really mean anything in such contexts. I think a non-native speaker would be better advised to just forget it.

Comment: better yet - fuhgedabowdit!

Comment: That's certainly true. On the other hand, slang is very localized (it's amusing to consider how a World English Slang Academy might work :-) and structures that get elided often get reconstructed elsewhere, as witness the invariable Indian English tag ", isn't it?". So maybe this is the way of the World; after all, there are far more non-native speakers of English than native.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I know you are picking on John, but is that supposed to mean anything?

Comment: @MichealCorleone, it means "forget about it", said with a supposedly mob-type accent. (you really didn't get that?)

Comment: @KristinaLopez lol..now I see it. I probably should have got it after watching Godfather, Goodfellas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you omitted “him” from your search, as you did in the body of your question (but not your title). A Google search on “the deal with him is” yields lots of hits.

“The deal with [so-and-so]” is a very common colloquial expression meaning approximately “the matter to be addressed concerning [so-and-so]” or “the matter which troubles me concerning [so-and-so]” or “the underlying fact concerning [so-and-so]”. Here are a few examples, from the Google search I just described:

- Omg whats the deal with him? is it flirting? —*a woman asks how to interpret a man’s behaviour.*
- [Q:]What is the deal with this guy? [...] whenever he is going against me, i just get destroyed. [A:] Basically the deal with him is hes really tanky and puts out a lot of burst damage —*a videogamer asks how to cope with a powerful opponent.*
- Ok here's the deal with him. Is he easy- yes. Is he one of the dullest teachers and least prepared I've ever met=- yes. —*post rating a history professor*

Such “deals” need not be with people; you can speak of “the deal with” any topic of concern:

- [Q:] I'm used to micromanaging everything in my machine [... ] my
  hardest challenge will just letting go and let the Mac do whatever
  magic it does [A:] This is not a thing. The deal with Macs is just
  that they tend not to cast support files to the 4 winds in complex
  installation routines.

It’s a useful expression, but not one I would recommend promoting to the formal register.